# Derivative without extrema is monotone

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

**UPDATE:** This question was cross-posted and answered on MathOverflow: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/444723/derivative-without-extrema-is-monotone

Let $f\colon(a,b)\to\mathbb R$ be differentiable on $(a,b)$ such that $f'$ has no local extrema on $(a,b)$. Is it true that $f'$ is necessarily monotone on $(a,b)$?

If $f'$ is assumed to be continuous on $(a,b)$ then this is definitely true. Indeed, by continuity of $f'$ each segment $[x_1,x_2]\subset(a,b)$ contains points of global maximum and minimum of $f'$ on this segment which must be attained at the endpoints of the segment (otherwise $f'$ will have a local extremum), so $\min\{f'(x_1),f'(x_2)\}\leq f'(x)\leq\max\{f'(x_1),f'(x_2)\}$ for any points $x_1<x<x_2$ in $(a,b)$, and the latter property can be shown to be equivalent to monotonicity.

However, derivatives can be discontinuous, and I'm not sure how to proceed in that case. I don't even know whether there exists a discontinuous derivative without extrema.

Comment: with local extrema do you mean isolated extrema, or would tor example the constant function have its own value as an extrema?

Comment: @linkja any extrema, regardless of whether they are isolated and/or strict.